# why is Get-CimInstance outputting same value everytime?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have a table like this

```
DBName  pserver      qserver
cube1   server1.com q1server.com    
cube1   server2.com q2server.com    
cube2   server3.com q3server.com    
cube2   server4.com q4server.com
```

i have the following code

```
param([float]$Threshold)

Function Query($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0] }

$PServers = Query "SELECT DISTINCT [pserver] FROM [dbo].[$Table]" | Select -ExpandProperty pserver;
$QServers = Query "SELECT DISTINCT [qserver] FROM [dbo].[$Table]" | Select -ExpandProperty qserver;

foreach($server in $PServers + $QServers)
{ 
    if(!$Threshold) 
    {
        [float]$Threshold = 0.00
        $cs = New-CimSession -ComputerName $server
        [float]$Threshold = ((Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory -CimSession $cs | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb)*0.7 

    }

    "$server: $Threshold"
}
```

on q1server.com, there is 200 GB memory, while the rest of the servers have 96GB memory.

if i run the threshold Cim code on a powershell on the q1server.com server, i get back 140GB which is correct due to the 0.7 multiplication

so i know that the threshold code is fine and working.

however, threshold in the forloop seems to always result in 67.20

the 67.20 is the result from the 96GB from the other servers, which is correct as well ONLY for the other servers. so why is it overriding q1server 140 GB threshold and just outputting 67.2GB?

[image]

it should be something like this

```
67.2
67.2
67.2
67.2
140
67.2
67.2
67.2
```

Comment: No exceptions being returned?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 nope. i wrapped it up in try catch and no exception either

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 wait i just tried something...i put the [float]$Threshold = 0.00 before the if(!$Threshold) and now its returning 140GB!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a logic error, you are having an if condition to check if no `$threshold` which is valid only for firs iteration. You could remove that check as it is not required.

Comment: but what if the users DO enter a threshold?

Comment: I ended up using a bool flag after param, something like `$Check = $false; if($Threshold) {$Check = $true}` and then in the foreach loop `foreach(...) { if($Check -eq $false) {[float]$Threshold = 0.0; ....}}`